# Winston log to array and flush to db in batch

Tags: node.js, logging, winston, bunyan

Is there a transport or mechanism that allows for logging to an in-memory structure like array and then flush to db once a while?

dont want to make an expensive db call for every log and hence want to do the flush of logs as a batch once a while to db.

Is there a sample or a way to use winston and bunyan to log to an array or some such structure?